# Objective-c Array not deallocating objects when removing

Tags: objective-c

```
// AClass.m
// init
enemyBullets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
enemy1 = [[Enemy alloc] initWithBullets:enemyBullets];

// At some point
NSMutableArray *bulletsToDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
for(BulletEnemy *thisBullet in enemyBullets)
{
    // If I have to delete
    [bulletsToDelete addObject: thisBullet];
}
[enemyBullets removeObjectsInArray:bulletsToDelete];

//dealloc method
[enemyBullets release];
[enemy1 release];
```

Now Inside Enemy some point in time I do the following:

```
// Enemy.m
- (id)initWithBullets:(NSMutableArray*) _bullets{
     // Enemybullets is a var of Enemy
     enemyBullets = _bullets;
}

// At some point...
myBullet = [[BulletEnemy alloc] init];
[enemyBullets addObject:myBullet];
[myBullet release];
```

The problem is when I do the following at Aclass:

```
[enemyBullets removeObjectsInArray:bulletsToDelete];
```

The dealloc method inside BulletEnemy doesn't get called  because the retain count isn't 0. Why? But If I release ACLass (which releases enemyBullets) then My bullets get deallocated.

Comment: Why doesn't `Enemy` retain the `EnemyBullets` array?  You don't seem to be following standard memory management practises.

Comment: Your "At some point" bit is very very strange. If you want to selectively delete things from the array, build an `NSMutableIndexSet` that contains the indexes of the objects you don't want and then use `-removeObjectsAtIndexes:`. Or just do a reverse enumeration and remove the object from the array immediately.

Comment: @trojanfoe, do I have to retain it? `enemyBullets = [_bullets retain]` To clear up, the dealloc gets called when I release Aclass, which relases enemyBullets.

Comment: Well firstly I would say that `[Enemy init]` should create the bullets array and you can then add *readonly* properly to the `Enemy` class so other objects can access the array and add to it.  It's not clear to me why the enemy owns the bullets anyway; aren't they sibling *objects* both appearing on the screen?

Comment: Enemy owns enemybullets so I can create and add BulletEnemy to the array. It is AClass that manages enemyBullets.

Comment: @KevinBallard, somepoint is an update method where I have to check if remove bullets or not.

Comment: @marcg11: You're doing it very inefficiently.

Comment: @KevinBallard, well AClass has to control enemybullets. Enemy can't retain enemybullets because there are a lot of enemies. I just want enemies to add a bullet to my enemybullets from AClass. It does it will and perfect, but it only releases the bullets once I release AClass. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently, I was asigning something with retain propery, which made the object +1 thus not to deallocate. Just changed the propery to assign and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make Enemy own the enemyBullets. And use reverseObjectEnumerator

```
// AClass.m
// init
enemy1 = [[Enemy alloc] init];

// At some point
for(BulletEnemy *thisBullet in enemy1.enemyBullets.reverseObjectEnumerator)
{
    // If I have to delete
    [enemy1.enemyBullets removeObject:thisBullet];
}

//dealloc method
[enemy1 release];

//Enemy.h
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* enemyBullets;


// Enemy.m
@synthesize enemyBullets = _enemyBullets;

- (id)init{
     // Enemybullets is a var of Enemy
     _enemyBullets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

// At some point...
myBullet = [[BulletEnemy alloc] init];
[enemyBullets addObject:myBullet];
[myBullet release];

-(void) dealloc{
    [_enemyBullets release];
}
```

Comment: What? No, I don't retain myBullet anywhere.

Comment: change to like this and same happens?
for(BulletEnemy *thisBullet in enemyBullets.reverseObjectEnumerator)
{
    [enemyBullets removeObject: thisBullet];
}

Comment: Or do you use blocks for myBullet any point? could be retain by blocks.

Comment: Nope no blocks. Try the reverseObjectEnumerator but still doesn't dealloc bullets when I remove them from enemyBullets.

Comment: code shows AClass owns enemyBullets because it doesn't release and it releasing at dealloc.

Comment: I assume you have multiple Enemy instance in AClass but only one enemyBullets and only release [enemyBullets release] one time. You should have retain enemyBullets in Enemy.m and should release enemyBullets after initWithBullets

Comment: So shouldn't I alloc enemybullets at AClass?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10900/discussion-between-marcg11-and-tomohisa-takaoka)

Comment: @TomohisaTakaoka: Your update to the removing bullets code is broken.

Comment: @KevinBallard Thanks, I have fixed to removeObject:

Comment: What you say is changing the whole structure of my project, because it's not as simple as I describe it here.

Comment: Yup, following ownership rule is key. see apple document... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf

Comment: Hm the problem seems that when I create myBullet = [[BulletEnemy alloc] init]; the retain count is directly 2, why?